# Deleting LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have different localStorage eg:

```
__user_information_1494653090436
__user_information_1494652962487
__user_information_1494653208375
```

where

> 1494653090436, 1494652962487, and 1494653208375

are different timestamp.

I am just thinking how to delete all the localStorage except the latest timestamp. Any help.

Comment: Have you considered clearing out all previous values before adding a new timestamp?

Comment: each time of create . delete the previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step needs to be getting all those keys from the localStorage. This can be done with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var allKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
```

Then you just find out which one is the latest and remove the rest

```
var sorted = allKeys 
  // Use regex to find your keys of interest
  .map(key => key.match(/__user_information_([0-9]+)/))
  // Filter out those that don't match
  .filter(match => !!match)
  // Sort by timestamp
  .sort((a, b) => {
    var a_ = parseInt(a[1]), b_ = parseInt(b[1]);
    return a_ > b_ ? 1
      : b_ > a_ ? -1
      : 0;
   });

// Remove all but last
for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) {
  localStorage.removeItem(sorted[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this method

```
if(new Date().getTime() > parseFloat(window.opt2))
    window.localStorage.removeItem('homeCookie')
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest time-stamp is the higherstamp.simply remove the higher value

```js
var local ={  //for example localstorage like this
date1:1494653090436,
date2:1494652962487,
date3:1494653208375,
}
var a =Object.values(local);
console.log(a.slice(0,a.indexOf(Math.max(...a)))) 
var removedkey = Object.keys(local)[a.indexOf(Math.max(...a))]//removed key
console.log(removedkey)
//window.localStorage.removeItem(removedkey)
```

Comment: So, for this i need to run a loop over localStorage to read the keys and then extract the timestamp. Correct?

Comment: hm, thank but again the problem is i will have all the keys if i say for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(key)
}, now how i can get the only specific keys where keys are dynamic.

Comment: @PriyaSingh see my updated answer.I was  add some example localstorage